# get_metadata_by_mid() not working on live server but works on local installation

Tags: wordpress

I am using `get_metadata_by_mid()` function to pull the term id and using that to get term name and it's slug.

Here is my code:

```
//$booking_id is passed to function and it's not empty (tested via echoing)
$term_data = get_metadata_by_mid('post', $booking_id);
$vendor_data = get_term_by( 'id', absint( $term_data->post_id ), 'wcpv_product_vendors' );
```

In the html I use `$vendor_data->name` & `$vendor_data->slug` variables to access them and it works on my local wordpress. But when I uploaded code on the live server the `$term_data` variable results nothing. Obviously `$vendor_data` will also be empty, as it doesn't receive `term_id`

It's very strange issue and I have no idea; what's wrong?

**NOTE:**

- running same version of wordpress on both environments (local and server)
- `$booking_id` var is not empty

Comment: in which template did you wrote that code?

Comment: `functions.php` in child theme

Comment: get_metadata_by_mid('post', $booking_id); -> maybe you have to use 'term instead of the 'post''

Comment: It is not working using `term` on local machine

Comment: Is the database identically on both machines? Because this sounds like it's not.